# Function returning the following days and months in python3

Tags: python-3.x, date, web-scraping

I am writing a webscraper and the URL is based on the dates:

```
checkin_month=2&checkin_monthday=21&checkin_year=2020&checkout_month=2&checkout_monthday=22
```

There are 4 variables: checkin day and month, and checkout day and month. Checkout day will be always be = checkin day + 1. But when the newmonth is ending, checkout day is 1 and checkout month = checkin month +1.
Is there any function or library I can use to somehow implement it or do I have to write my own code to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use: 
`from datetime import timedelta`

then :

```
yourDate += timedelta(days=1)
```

This previous code increments your date by one day. But, to increment the date, your date must be of type datetime.

Below, the documentation of thhis class.
    class datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)

You can see a tutorial to manipulate date here : https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-datetime-tutorial/